# check the property fields and return array using javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, object

I would like to how to check the property fields is true,
then push the strings to array using javascript

- If `kid` is true, then push the string `kidexists`,
- If `country` is true, then push the string `cnexists`,
- If `details` is true, then push the string `dtsexists`,

Code tried:

```js
var itemList1 = [
  {id:1, kid: true, country: true, details: false},
  {id:2, kid: true, country: false, details: true},
  {id:3, kid: true, country: false, details: false}
]

var itemList2 = [
  {id:1, kid: false, country: true, details: false},
  {id:2, kid: true, country: false, details: false},
]

var r1 = this.result(itemList1)
var r2 = this.result(itemList2)

console.log("R1:", r1);
console.log("R2:", r2);

function result(items){
  let finalResult=[]
  for (let i of items) {
    if (i.kid) {
      finalResult.push('kidexists');
    } else if (i.country) {
      finalResult.push('cnexists');
    } else if (i.details) {
      finalResult.push('dtsexists');
    }
    finalResult =  [...new Set(finalResult)];
    return finalResult;
  }
}
```

ExpectedOutPut for `itemList1`

```
['kidexists', 'cnexists', 'dtsexists'];
```

ExpectedOutPut for `itemList2`

```
['kidexists', 'cnexists'];
```

Comment: You wrote 2 times `ExpectedOutPut` and never the actual output, which one is what ?

Comment: @Elikill58 thanks for reply, its when i pass itemList1, then itemList2

Comment: Ok I see, I fixed your code and answered :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You made 2 things wrong :

1. You were returning result too fast. You should not return it into the for list as others items will not be take in count
2. With `else if`, others if were never called and so, values were ignored. By using only "if", it works

Code that works fine:

```js
var itemList1 = [
  {id:1, kid: true, country: true, details: false},
  {id:2, kid: true, country: false, details: true},
  {id:3, kid: true, country: false, details: false}
]

var itemList2 = [
  {id:1, kid: false, country: true, details: false},
  {id:2, kid: true, country: false, details: false},
]

var r1 = this.result(itemList1)
var r2 = this.result(itemList2)

console.log("R1:", r1);
console.log("R2:", r2);

function result(items){
  let finalResult = new Set();
  for (let i of items) {
    if (i.kid) {
      finalResult.add('kidexists');
    }
    if (i.country) {
      finalResult.add('cnexists');
    }
    if (i.details) {
      finalResult.add('dtsexists');
    }
  }
  return [...finalResult];
}
```

As proposed by InSync, `finalResult` is directly a `Set` (and so, we're using `add` instead of `push`).

Comment: `finalResult` should be initialized as a `Set`.